# Hint for getting started on $L_1$-norm question

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be equipped with $L_1$-norm, how do I show that the set $X$ is dense in $L_1$, where $X$ is the set with all elements ${x\in{L^1}}$ such that $${\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}n{|}x_n{|}<\infty}?$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $(y_n) \in L^1$ be arbitrary. Given a small $\varepsilon > 0$, we want to find $(x_n) \in X$ such that
$$
\|(x_n) - (y_n)\|_{L^1} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |x_n - y_n| < \varepsilon.
$$
Here's a hint. Note that the head sequence $(z_n) := (y_1, \dots, y_N, 0, 0, \dots)$ is an element of $X$. What do you get if you compute $\|(z_n) - (y_n)\|_{L^1}$?